# Oracle 11g : staging table

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need Oracle 11g commands to create staging table.

```
table: Streets
Input field: Name 
output fields: Streets_Prefix
               Streets_Name
               Streets_Suffix
```

End users from a front end application fill information for only "Name" fields of "Streets" table as :

> "AVE Mandela road South".

But in same table "Streets" other fields need to get parsed data from "Name" fields as :

```
Streets_Prefix : AVE

Streets_Name : Mandela road

Streets_Suffix : South
```

So here input and target table is same "Streets" but input and target fields are different so I need command to create staging table in which I can do Parsing of 'Name' field and update "Streets_Prefix", "Streets_Name" and "Streets_Suffix".

Comment: Okay, thanks for sharing. Do you have a question?

Comment: Yes, I need Oracle 11g commands to create staging table for table "Streets". Please read thoroughly.

Comment: Buth, have you tried something you need help with, or do you want to hire a programmer? Please be clear about a specific problem you are having trouble with (creating the table, parsing the address, etc) and share the code and results of any attempt you have made. Stack Overflow is not a website where you can just dump your specs and someone will do your project.

Comment: Golez, I am not Oracle guy, that's why I posted my issue in this forum to get hep how to create a staging table. If you think it absurd to get help you can delete my post if you have admin rights or atleast give me hint how can I resolve my issue.

Comment: I have this python code for parsing data, import arcpy
env.workspace = "C:/ArcTutor/geocoding/atlanta.gdb"

# Set local variables:
input_feature_class = "streets"
address_fields = "ID;FULL_STREET_NAME"
locator_style = "US Address-Dual Ranges"
standardized_fields = "PreDir;PreType;StreetName;SufType;SufDir"
standardized_feature_class = "StandardizedStreet"

arcpy.StandardizeAddresses_geocoding(input_feature_class, address_fields, locator_style, standardized_fields, standardized_feature_class, "Static")

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below queries to get the Streets_Prefix, Streets_Name,Streets_Suffix populated from `Name` column of `STREETS` table

```
select 
     substr(name, 0, instr(name,' ',1)-1) 
     as Streets_Prefix 
from STREETS  ;


select 
     substr(name, instr(name, ' ')+1,instr(name, ' ', -1, 1) - instr(name, ' ') - 1)
      as Streets_Name 
from STREETS  ;


select 
     substr(name, instr(name,' ',-1)+1) 
     as Streets_suffix
from STREETS  ;
```

OUTPUT:

### STREETS_PREFIX

AVE
star
ZEBRA

### STREETS_NAME

Mandela road
Bangalore road
CROSSING road

### STREETS_SUFFIX

South
East
NORTH

```
create table STREETS  ( name varchar2(200)); --Considering you want only one column
```

For further reference :  [CREATE TABLE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables003.htm#ADMIN01503)

Comment: Further, you can create a PL/SQL block or a trigger to update these values  automatically update these values as and when the base table STREETS is updated or a row is inserted(use a temporary table)

Comment: Thanks Mahendra, provided select statement is quite helpful. Can you also help me to provide command to create a staging table.

Comment: @TARUNPUNETHA Updated the answer. Please check. Also there is link provided to see if you want to add other columns in table with different data types.Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad. Please accept the answer if it works for you. @TARUNPUNETHA. So that others will know that the question has been answered.

Comment: Learn here on how to accept answers; http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow